# Regex form checking with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, webforms

I'm having some real difficulty with javascript.

What I'm trying to do is validate user input from an HTML form.

I have two events for html:

```
<form action="attendproc.asp" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button" onClick="return submitForm()">
```

Here is my javascript:

```
//Confirm form submission
function submitForm() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this form?") == false) {return false} 
    else {return true}
}

//Validate form input
function validateForm(form) {

    fail = validDate(form.date.value)
    fail += validNum(form.jsia.value)
    fail += validNum(form.jsga.value)
    fail += validNum(form.yvcia.value)
    fail += validNum(form.yvcga.value)

    if (fail == "") {return true}
    else {alert(fail) return false}
}

function validDate(field) {
    if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(field) == false) {return "Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date.\n"} 
    else {return ""}
}

function validNum(field) {
    if (isNaN(field)) {return "Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.\n"} 
    else {return ""}
}
```

Notice that I'm using RegEx to validate my desired date format. I know for certain the submitForm() function works. My pain is from the other three functions. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To elaborate on Shaun's comment: What is your question? What kind of "pain" are you encountering? Do you get an error message? an unexpected result? The more specific you can be, the more likely that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

> Shaun

I finally fixed it.

```
//Confirm form submission
function submitForm() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this form?") == false) {return false;} 
    else {return true;}
}
//Validate attendance form input
function validateAttendForm(form) {

    fail = validDate(form.date.value);
    fail += validNum(form.jsia.value);
    fail += validNum(form.jsga.value);
    fail += validNum(form.yvcia.value);
    fail += validNum(form.yvcga.value);

    if (fail == "") {return true;}
    else {alert(fail); return false;}
}

function validDate(field) {
    re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
    if (re.test(field) == false) {return "Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date.\n";} 
    else {return "";}
}

function validNum(field) {
    if (isNaN(field) || field != parseInt(field)) {return "Invalid input. Please enter a valid interger.\n";}
    else {return "";}
}
```

It was an issue with the syntax I used for my validDate() function. It was pretty much a plug and play fix.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from shady formating, there's definately one thing that will cause problems.

isNaN(field)
should be: isNaN(parseInt(field))

IsNaN evaluates to true only with NaN, and string is not a NaN. ParseInt attempts to parse an int from a string, and returns either a number, or a NaN.

Comment: What do you mean by shady formatting? I'd like to improve my code as well as I can.

Comment: Nothing very important, just minor things like redundant if in submitForm (could just as well be return confirm(...)), two quite long lines, no whitespace between curly brackets.